# AWS ECS Scheduled Task Not Logging to CloudWatch

Tags: amazon-ecs, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I have a task scheduled in ECS that is known to work both when run manually via the "Run New Task" option and when left to run as a `cron` expression.

However, the logs only seem to appear in CloudWatch when I run the task manually (using the same task definition, settings, etc.). When run via a scheduled task, the logs do not appear.

I've verified in CloudTrail that the task did run successfully when scheduled and there appear to be no errors, either.

Has anyone else come up against this? I've done some digging online, and while I have seen mention of it, no one has posted a resolution or answer as far as I can tell.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have the exact same issue. It seems to be related to the fact that when you manually run a task, you go through ECS, but Scheduled Tasks are built onto Cloudwatch (therefore we may be missing some permission to write logs in this execution context).

Comment: I have the same issue and AWS tech support has not been able to explain why this happens and how to fix this. They verified that all configurations are correct. Works when deployed using CDK but not when using SAM.